# Accessing containerized Django app from ECS public IPv4 endpoint

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, docker

I have a dockerized django app that is stored in `ECR`.  When I set-up a new `ECS` cluster (using `Fargate`), this image loads correctly and I can see the logs in `Cloudwatch`:

```
20:12:21 Operations to perform:
20:12:21 Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
20:12:21 Running migrations:
20:12:21 No migrations to apply.
20:12:23 No changes detected
20:12:25 Watching for file changes with StatReloader
20:12:25 Performing system checks...
20:12:25 System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
20:12:26 June 22, 2019 - 20:12:26
20:12:26 Django version 2.2.2, using settings 'config.settings'
20:12:26 Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
20:12:26 Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

but when I got to the public ipv4 listed under the task network details, and go to :8000 in my browser, nothing loads and I dont see any requests going to the server in the container in cloud watch.

I'm wondering if the issue is related to using:
`python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` in my container set-up or alternatively, a setting in the security group, etc. 
But i've allowed inbound traffic to `127.0.0.1` & `0.0.0.0` port `8000` inside the settings there already.

I'm somewhat at a loss as I've looked around at a variety of documentation and I seem to have my configuration set similarly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to map your host port to container port if your container is running in bridge mod Something like `docker run -p <port>:8000`.to view it on browser as `public_ip:port` Similar configuration you have to do in fargate.

Answer (score 0):

Check if in AWS Control panel for Fargate this particular container definition have correct port mapping. 
In your case, you need to map to port: `8000` as your app is listening on that port. Also, you need to create that app in a container is listening to `0.0.0.0`, not `127.0.0.1` ( At least from log port I can see you bind it to `127.0.0.1`